# Is it appropriate to use <dl> tag in my case?

Tags: html, xhtml

I am designing some web page. One page will be only for "Contract details page", where will be only details about contract in this form:

General information

- ID of contract: 132456
- Date          : 18. 11. 2014
- Current value :    200000 Euro
- Participant   : Robin Hood
- ...and others

So, my question: Is it appropriate to use `<dl>` tag in this case?
Some code like this:

```
<dl>
    <dt>ID</dt>
    <dd>123456</dd>

    <dt>Date</dt>
    <dd>18. 11. 2014</dd>

    <dt>Current value</dt>
    <dd>200000 EURO</dd>

    <dt>Participant</dt>
    <dd>Robin Hood</dd>
</dl>
```

Is there any alternative for this? Put these information to form(labels, spans)?

Thank you very much for your advice!

Comment: Seems like a perfectly good idea, however this is, absolutely, opinion-based unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for comments. Some guy said me that this is not appropriate for this application in semantic side, but I think that <dl> tag is especially for that case...

Comment: I would say it's exactly for this case

Comment: When someone says “semantic” in the HTML context, it’s usually just an opinion (often an odd one) purported to be a fact. In this specific issue, the realistic alternatives are `dl` and `table`. They are just two *structures*, with different default rendering. The choice between them is subjective and not very important.